# why i get TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set my authentication views in my locallibrary site and these are my codes :

My projects urls.py file has these

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += [
   path(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
   re_path(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

templates :

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['./templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Comment: `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),`

Answer (score 0):

```py
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath("templates"))], # this points templates in the root directory
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
  },
]
```

now inside the `templates` folder

```markdown
$ ls -al templates/registrations
|
|--login.html
|--password_change_done.html
|
|...
```

That should solve your problem! Create a Templates folder in the root directory and inside it a registration folder

`$ sudo mkdir -p templates/registrations`

Also what @whatwillem-van-onsem said